# Browser displays gibberish from php

Tags: php, apache-2.4, lamp

I am moving an existing PHP/MySQL web application to a CentOS 6.8 Apache server. I can view phpinfo() in the browser just fine, but when I attempt to browse home.php, I see a whole page of gibberish like this:

Zend2002062301111863910x� �2�Y=oGH"P@�BH���8����թH�"�[�x���G�wt����*I

The new site was setup using WHM/cpanel, but I have root ssh access to modify config files. I'm guessing that there is an Apache module that needs to be enabled somewhere.

Can anyone suggest what I might try next? 
Thank you!

Comment: One possibility is that you are serving content compressed, but either the headers to tell the browser about the compression are not present or its compressed with a method the browser doesn't support.

Comment: Answer: As it turned out, we needed to install Zen Guard to decode the content. This solved the problem.